# Programmatically modify WIF service configuration in .NET 4.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, wif, claims-based-identity

Using WIF with .NET 4.5 in MVC4 app with Ninject

Here's the situation - I have a custom `ClaimsAuthenticationManager` subclass called `TenantAccessClaimsAuthenticationManager` that does some claims transformation. The `TenantAccessClaimsAuthenticationManager` needs a IRepository object to be injected into it (using ninject).

The .NET 4.5 impl of WIF suggests that I can stick my custom claims authentication manager in the web.config - however, this approach can only instantiate the object via  a no-args ctor.

The second approach I had is to not have anything int the web.config, but in `App_start`, get a handle to the WIF configuration and stick in the `TenantAccessClaimsAuthenticationManager` in `RegisterServices`

How do I get a handle to the currently application's WIF configuration context?  MSDN docs aren't helping.

**Edit:** Obviously the problem is that the `onServiceConfigurationCreated` event is no longer available. What's the best way to do this now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event is still available!

code://System.IdentityModel.Services:4.0.0.0:b77a5c561934e089/System.IdentityModel.Services.FederatedAuthentication/event:FederationConfigurationCreated:System.EventHandler

More specifically, the event is available at [FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfigurationCreated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.services.federatedauthentication.federationconfigurationcreated(v=vs.110).aspx). An example implementation is below:

```
FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfigurationCreated += (sender, e) => {
    e.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.ClaimsAuthenticationManager = new MyCustomClaimsAuthenticationManager();
}
```

There's a blog post at http://dunnry.com/blog/2012/12/20/SettingClaimsAuthenticationManagerProgrammaticallyInNET45.aspx with more information.